# Annoying shrill outgoing Facetime ring tone

Tags: iphone, facetime, ringtones

Is there anyway to stop the FaceTime ringtone heard on an outgoing call? I have tried the iPhone mute button and FaceTime mute icon with no success.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible without switching output device to another connected device which is muted, such as a bluetooth speaker or car stereo, or jailbreaking to delete the audio file from the filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

You can't actually mute it but you can reduce to a very low level, simply with the volume buttons. It will remember your settings for future calls.

Answer (score 0):

Use earphones whilst it's calling and when it's connecting take them out.